# RXJS - Execute function if a specific condition is met on a value from a observable

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have built a search field with autocomplete. I'm listening to a observable that detects changes from a text field.

```
this.term.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .filter(query=>query.toString().length>1)
        .subscribe(query => { 

         //Execute search function and populate dropdown menu

        })
```

When a user search for a string the dropdown autocomplete list is populated with suggestions. If the user then erases the search string I want the dropdown list to be removed. Is there a RxJS function that makes it possible to execute a function before subscribe if a specific condition is met on the value generated from the observable stream?

Comment: you could also move the filter inside the subscription and use control flow there. If `more than one character` do the usual, if no characters (erasal of search string) do something else. Looks like the simplest solution, though not the more maintainable.

Comment: That's is what I've done so far but I thought that maybe a more elegant solution existed using one of the many rxjs methods.

Comment: Your question seems ill-framed though. Subscription happens only once, the erasal of the search string can happen any number of times. So even if such a Rxjs operator would exist, it would not help you. In the end, what you want is a way to add control flow to your dataflow, in a way that is maintainable. Taking a clue from MVI, I would use a `event -> intent -> action` dataflow, with two intents : `erasal`, `updated_search`, and corresponding actions : `fetch_suggestions`, `remove_dropdown_list` and subscribe to that. The control flow is added through normal `if` inside the operators you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
this.term.valueChanges
    .debounce(100)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(() => /* close list here */)
    .where(val => val.length > 1)
    .select(query => ({ 
        query: query, 
        completions: completions
            .filter(w => w.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
    }))
    .subscribe(r => {
        /*
         * r.query          contains the current search word
         * r.completions    contain the completions for that word
         */
    });
```

Working basic example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wh55g4x5/6/)